# Cosine similarities between users in movielens 1M dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, networkx

I want to calculate cosine similarities between users in movielense 1m dataset. I tried to use one hot encoding to do so. This approach is not a good idea since it requires so much RAM. Can anyone suggest a better approach for this problem?

```
df = pd.read_table("ml-1m/ratings.dat", sep="::",names=['user','id','rating','-'])
df_i = pd.get_dummies(data['item_id'])
data[ list(df_i.columns) ] = df_i
data.drop('item_id', inplace=True, axis=1)
data.drop('timestamp',axis=1,inplace=True)
A_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(A)
for i in range(1,1683):    
   data[i] = data[i]*data['rating']   
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity    
user_relation = cosine_similarity(df,df, dense_output=True)
```

Comment: (1) You can try dimension reduction methods, and then apply cosine sim to those (e.g PCA, tSNE, U-Map) look each one carefully as they differ in some aspects. (2) Somehow get model embeddings (neural nets) (you probably need to train a basic model first).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.